# How to link to ACML on Windows 64 bits using qmake?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, x86-64, qmake

I'm using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) to simplify my C++ development. To project works fine in both Linux and Windows (64 bits for both). I'm using Qt Creator + qmake to build the project to keep a single toolset across platforms.

I directly include Armadillo in my project. As it is a template library, it does not require compilation; including the header is enough.

Now I would like to use [AMD's Core Math Library (ACML)](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/) to speed things up as it is freely available on both Linux and Windows. I thus setup Armadillo's config.hpp to use LAPACK+BLAS through ACML using:

```
#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK
#define ARMA_USE_BLAS
#define ARMA_BLAS_CAPITALS
```

On Linux, the compilation+linking works correctly. My qmake project file contains this:

```
unix: {
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/acml/gfortran/
    LIBS += -L/usr/lib/acml/gfortran/ -lacml_mp
}
```

Using *ldd* on the resulting executable reveals the shared library dependency on /usr/lib/acml/gfortran/libacml_mp.so.

On Windows though, I cannot find the right linking flag to link against ACML. I used [acml5.3.1-ifort64.exe](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/cpu-development/amd-core-math-library-acml/acml-downloads-resources/#download) which was compiled using Intel's Fortran compiler for 64 bits Windows. According to the PDF manual (included in acml's archive as acml.pdf, section 2.3.2), linking dynamically on Windows is done this way:

```
cl driver.c -Ic:\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp\include c:\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp\lib\libacml_mp_dll.lib
```

with the path changed to the right one, of course (*cl* is not the linker but the compiler...)

So basically, it should be just adding the *libacml_mp_dll.lib* file to the linking command.

Unfortunately, I cannot link correctly. I added this to the qmake project file on Windows:

```
LIBS += $$quote(C:\AMD\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp\lib\libacml_mp_dll.lib)
```

The path is fine, the file exists, etc.

I keep getting linking errors, the first one being (and all others being similar):

```
file.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sgetrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::getrf<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,int *)" (??$getrf@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN000@Z)
```

The symbol *sgetrf_* is a LAPACK function that should be provided by ACML.

How can I link correctly? Am I setting qmake correctly for it to find the ACML libs?

Thanks a lot for any hints!

Edit: I checked how the linker was called by the qmake generated makefile and tried to work from there. This is how the linker is called when I don't enable ACML at all (the obj files are put into a tmp file which disappear after make is called, so I just put "debug/*.obj" to include all objects):

```
link.exe  /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='*******************' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\project.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\project.exe debug/*.obj /LIBPATH:C:\Boost\1.54.0\lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\bin" hdf5.lib hdf5_hl.lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\lib"
```

I then manually added the library to the linker command. I tried these:

```
link.exe  /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='*******************' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\project.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\project.exe debug/*.obj /LIBPATH:C:\Boost\1.54.0\lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\bin" hdf5.lib hdf5_hl.lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\lib" /LIBPATH:C:\AMD\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp\lib libacml_mp_dll.lib
link.exe  /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='*******************' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\project.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\project.exe debug/*.obj /LIBPATH:C:\Boost\1.54.0\lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\bin" hdf5.lib hdf5_hl.lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\lib" C:\AMD\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp\lib\libacml_mp_dll.lib
link.exe  /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='*******************' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\project.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\project.exe C:\AMD\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp\lib\libacml_mp_dll.lib debug/*.obj /LIBPATH:C:\Boost\1.54.0\lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\bin" hdf5.lib hdf5_hl.lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.8.11\lib"
```

but every one on these commands fail with the same linker error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the BLAS included with ACML does not have underscore as suffix. Armadillo's ARMA_BLAS_UNDERSCORE flag thus have to be *commented* in config.hpp:

```
// #define ARMA_BLAS_UNDERSCORE
```

The qmake configuration I'm using is the following:

```
win32: {
    ACMLDIR = $$quote(C:\AMD\acml5.3.1\ifort64_mp)
    INCLUDEPATH += $$quote($$ACMLDIR\include)
    LIBS += -L$$quote($$ACMLDIR\lib) -llibacml_mp_dll
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error:

```
File.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sgetrf_
```

where the compiler is complaining about the function name *sgetrf_*.  Notice that it's all in lowercase.  Does ACML need Blas and Lapack function names to be all in capitals?

I recommend checking to see if you have ARMA_BLAS_CAPITALS enabled in both your Linux and Window installations of Armadillo.

Comment: ARMA_BLAS_CAPITALS should be defined, but I will double-check on Monday. I remember playing with the flag and seeing linking error to SGETRF_ and others, instead of sgetrf_. I think ACML does require capitalization. Additionally, I don't have an installation of Armadillo; I put it directly in my project. It's a template library so does not need compilation, only #include'ing.

Comment: Activating ARMA_BLAS_CAPITALS gives the same linking error, but with symbol SGETRF_ instead of sgretrf_.

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe ACML also prefers not to have an underscore at the end of functions? Try commenting out ARMA_BLAS_UNDERSCORE.  Otherwise, I suggest asking AMD/ACML developers what happened to the sgetrf_() function.  Or perahps there is more than one ACML library to link with ?  (eg. LAPACK functions are in one library, and BLAS functions in another)

Comment: You guesses right! ARMA_BLAS_UNDERSCORE //had// to be //commented// (to disable appending the underscore)... I can link successfully.

Comment: Good to hear this is sorted. To clarify this further: does the Linux version of ACML require the underscore to be disabled as well?